# Send list from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Why is `kosarasVM.kosare.count` equal to zero?
The view works great but when I send the model back to the controller I can't get the list from the model.
I am new to MVC so sorry if this is the basic question

This is my model:

```
 public class UserKosarasVM
    {
        public UserKosarasVM()
        {
            Kosare = new List<KosaraVM>();
        }
        public List<KosaraVM> Kosare;
    }
```

This is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Izracunaj", "Kosaras", Model))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Kosare)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArtiklVM.Naziv)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Kolicina, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Kolicina, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArtiklVM.Cjena)
                </td>
    </tr>

        }
               <td>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Izracunaj</button>
        </td>       
    </div>
}
```

This is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Izracunaj([Bind(Include = "Kosare")] UserKosarasVM kosarasVM)
    {

            decimal ukupnaCjena = 0;
            foreach (var kosaraVM in kosarasVM.Kosare)
            {
                ukupnaCjena += kosaraVM.ArtiklVM.Cjena;
            }

            ViewBag.ukupnaCjena = ukupnaCjena;

            return View("Index", kosarasVM);
    }
```

---

```
enter code here
```

---

Comment: Please use the Chrome Developer Tools to see the payload you are posting to the server. Please copy and paste that payload into your question above.

Comment: Specify POST method like this: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Izracunaj", "Kosaras", FormMethod.Post))` & `@model UserKosarasVM` in view side, have you learned how to bind a viewmodel before?

Comment: offcourse but stil kosare in controller is empty